# How to create SMB iPhone/iPad client application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, share, smb

I can smell a smoke from my head a little bit.

I'm trying to create an iPhone/iPad application which can find computers in the network and then browse their shared directories and for example read some documents, play videos and so on. It would be great to do it with SMB protocol because you don't have to install it on that computers (like Win, ...). Bonjour looks pretty good but it is not installed by default on the comptures with windows. I've been looking for some library which I could include and use but with no success. I found something about libsmbclient but with no idea how to add it to my project (read something about cross-compiling but I believe in the easier way). Also XBMC crossed my way of looking for something but still with no idea how to use it for my intention.

Could someone please give me a hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To use Samba on iOS (Apple TV2), it is possible to lookup SMB devices in your network,
Have a look at my post here : http://imho.nu/iMHo/installing-smb/

Comment: That link is definitely not a technology site!

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't have SMB protocol. There is a package in Cydia that implmen

Comment: Yes I read something about it. But I want it in the proper way. So there is no chance how to do it (except implementing all the stuff by myself)?

Comment: There is no way, and i don't think that Apple approve an App that use a external file sharing protocol that have access to filesystem

Comment: HmHm, ok I get it. But how about BUZZ Player and some other? They are using samba pretty good. I also read something about XBMC but I'm quite confused about it-how to use it in my app (if it is even possible)... How did that BUZZ Player guys do that? They wrote it all by themselves? No, I really doubt it.

Comment: How do you know that they use SAMBA?

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/filebrowser-access-files-on/id364738545?mt=8 this uses SMB